# The sphere is a manifold?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, spherical-coordinates, parametrization

Given a manifold $M$ and open neighborhood $U \subset M$:

Map: $x: U \rightarrow \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^m$

Local parametrization: $F := x^{-1} : \Omega \rightarrow U \subset M$

If I now consider a sphere as a manifold, i.e. $M = \mathbb{S}^2$, then we can write:

$$M = [(x,y,z)\ | \ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = R]$$

A sphere can be described with spherical coordinates, means:

$$x_1 = R \ \cos\theta\ \cos\varphi$$

$$x_2 = R \ \cos\theta\ \sin\varphi$$

$$x_3 = R \ \sin\theta$$

Here $\varphi \in [0,2\pi)$ and $\theta \in [0,\pi)$. But if now

$$x(\varphi,\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\\ x_2 \\\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

is the map, then $M = [0,2\pi) \times [0,\pi)$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ describes the sphere. In addition, the local parametrization is

$$ \varphi = \text{arctan2} (x_1,x_2), \hspace{25pt} \theta = \arcsin \frac{x_3}{R}$$

However, this does not seem to be correct. What is my thinking error?

Comment: I don't quite understand but is your problem that you write $ M = [0,2\pi] \times [0,pi]$ (you missed a factor of 2)? Because Then you confuse the coordinate range with the manifold. The coordinates $(\phi,\theta)$ are part of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and used to label a point but are obtained by the mapping above. Also if you say $\mathbb{S}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ then you embedd the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and introduce a coordinate system by the embedding, but the sphere as a manifold exists also without the embedding and does not need to be thought of as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @DerHutmacher The point is: I am trying to find an example of a manifold and find a map and a parametrization for it, since my dear math professor thinks that definitions and proofs make a good enough skirpt, and examples and applications only distract from the math. The internet claims that the sphere is a manifold. So now I tried to find a map and a parametrization for it. But this does not work. But I can prove the regular value theorem. Great understanding of manifolds that I have here.

Comment: It is all good, in my view your answer works, the only problem being that your parametrization doesn't cover the whole sphere, which is fine, you need more than one chart to cover the whole sphere. As a simple example you can divide the sphere into two half planes z>0 and z < 0 and use the projection $(x,y,\pm z) \mapsto (x,y)$, what you then still do not have covered from the sphere is the equator $z=0$, to cover it you can use the analogous maps with the dividing planes $x=0$ and $y=0$ .

Comment: A manifold does not have to be covered by  a _single_ map. In fact most don't otherwise they would be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. It is enough to have multiple maps covering the whole manifold and "coordinated" at their intersections.

Comment: Here is another very useful parametrization for the (unit) sphere that easily generalizes to higher dimensions. Let $N$ be the north pole $(0,0,1)$. For each point of the sphere $p \ne N$, you can draw the line from $N$ thru $p$. This line will intersect the $xy$-plane at some point $q$. The map $f_N : p \mapsto q$ is a chart whose domain is the entire sphere except $N$. If you do the same thing for the south pole $S$, you get two charts that cover the entire sphere. And $f_S\circ f_N^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism of the punctured plane with itself, demonstrating that the sphere is a manifold.